# Compiling shared project in solution for x86 platform

Tags: c#-4.0, jenkins, msbuild, cil, target-platform

I have problem with MSIL dll after build solution.
I have 2 solution build one by one. Solution are builded on Jenkins with these parameters:

```
/t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFramework=v4.0 /p:Platform=x86
```

Solution 1

- Project A
- Project B
- Project C

Solution 2

- Project D
- Project E
- Project F - has project reference to Project A. Project A is not included to Solution 2.

All project has output to common\bin folder. After build ends, in bin folder I find Project A builded in MSIL. Solution 2 replace it these dll.

I use MSBUILD from .NET 4.0.30319 folder.

I remove from solution AnyCPU and Mixed mode. Alse I removed this configuration from each project.

How to tell MSBUILD to build each project in x86 platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing the right thing. Its just you need to use /p:PlatformTarget=x86 instead of     /p:Platform=x86

Comment: Without /p:Platform=x86 property solution is builded in "Release|x64".

Executing the command cmd.exe /C " c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFramework=v4.0 /p:PlatformTarget=x86

ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|x64".

Comment: That might be because default settings might have changed. If you look at the file Microsoft.Cpp.Default at the location C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0. Open it in notepad. You will see at the start: <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)' == ''"> </Platform> which tells you default platform. Note here, it's Platform not platFormTarget. For verification: If it is working fine with PlatformTarget then even if you remove it, it will work then as well :)